# Flutter globals variables are not refreshed when hot reload

Tags: flutter, dart

I start with flutter and I would like to learn more. In order to make my life easier, I declared global variables when I started my application.

The errorMessage variable is null at startup.

But if it fills up because it finds an error in the execution and displays the message to me, it does not return to null when I hot reload my application and keeps the error message which blocks me.

```
class HomeController extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeController({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _HomeControllerState createState() => _HomeControllerState();
}

class _HomeControllerState extends State<HomeController> {

  String errorMessage; // => My exemple of global variable
  bool debugFunctionStart = true;

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
...
```

And an exemple of function in my application :

```
functionChoose(List item,String key, int value){
    Map<String, dynamic> result;
    if(item.length > 0){
      List selectedInList = item.where((c) => c[key] == value).toList();
      result = selectedInList.first;
    }else{
      errorMessage = "ERROR ! not works ...";// => found an error
      print(errorMessage);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

How to do that ?

Comment: It's expected; the purpose of "hot reload" vs. "hot restart" is that "hot reload" preserves your application state and rebuilds widgets.  See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload#recent-code-change-is-included-but-app-state-is-excluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be because hot reloading saves the current state, just restart the app by clicking the green circular arrow if you're on vscode, and this should fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It was for be sure that there was nothing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Hot reload keeps states it is intended behavior

You can set `errorMessage` to null in state `reasseble()` method

> Called whenever the application is reassembled during debugging, for
> example during hot reload.

Afterall I would recomend you to read about [statemanagement](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro)